# Locate patterns

Tags: regex, linux, grep, locate

I am trying to locate all files on a linux server that fit this profile:

> sfvhebviweuiber9.html
>   sfvhebviweuiber11.html
>   jdjhwn2jjsfy2q10.html

Where the first `10-15` characters are `a-z`, followed by `[1-15]`, then `.html`.

How can I use `locate` (or any other method) to find all files that fit this profile?

The differences are basically the first `10-15` characters as they are made up of random alphabet characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't quite get the "[1-15]" part of your description, but I think this would do.  You can refine the `.*` part in the regex

```
locate -r '[a-z]\{10,15\}.*html'
```

Comment: `[a-z]\{10,15}\(\d\|1[0-5]\)\.html` That is, 10 to 15 letters, followed by a number or followed by a '1' and one number from 0-5.